# Laravel Paginate Not Working with ::where(...)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, pagination

I'm having an issue with Laravel's `->paginate()` method. Basically, I have a dynamic query that, based on the `GET` parameters passed to the controller, has or does not have a `::where()` clause in it. Without the `::where()`, I can call `->paginate(100)` and split the result set into pages of 100. When trying to do the same thing with `::where(...)->paginate(100)` I get 0 results.

At first I thought my query was wrong, but removing the `->paginate(100)` and replacing it with `->get()` returns the expected number of results. Here is the complete code:

```
$search = ((Input::get("search") != "") ? Input::get("search"):"");
$field = ((Input::get("field") != "") ? Input::get("field"):"");
if($search != "" && $field != ""){
    $templates = Template::where($field, "LIKE", $search)
    ->orderBy($sort, $order)
    ->paginate(100); // Fails (0 Results)
    ->get(); // Works (3 Results)
} else {
    $templates = Template::orderBy($sort, $order)
    ->paginate(100);  
}
```

I'm not sure why `->paginate()` is returning 0 results. Also, `dd($templates)` returns the entire `object(Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator)` collection, which has my results, but not in an accessible way. If you want to see the result I'm talking about, run `dd()` on a query without `->get(), ->first() or ->paginate()`

Comment: Try to get each object in `foreach`. Have you tried it ??

Comment: @ArkarAung Yes, that's not the issue. It doesn't return any results that I *can* loop through.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out the solution this morning, seems I needed to sleep the issue off. Basically, when I called the search method, along with `$_GET`ing the `field=example&search=test`, it would also send the current page, for example `page=2`. Now, if the result set returned < 100 results, page 2 wouldn't exist, and no results would be returned (because of `limit 100 offset 100`) in the query. Making the search function `$_GET` the base URL without the page properly linked to `page=1` and showed the results I was expecting.

Comment: Hi Tim, I'm getting this same exact problem but I'm not understanding this answer. Can you please post the exact code that got yours working, if you still have access to it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Try like this `'%'.$search.'%'`

```
$templates = Template::where($field, "LIKE", '%'.$search.'%')
    ->orderBy($sort, $order)
    ->paginate(100);
```

Comment: I realize I missed the `%` for searches, but that's not the issue here. Even if the query is correct, it doesn't paginate the results.